# JSX syntax in .js files gives an error in VS 2017

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have a simple project in VS Code using React. All my javascript files are with a `.js` extension, including the files with react components, which apparently use the jsx syntax.

[image]

I decided to open my project in VS 2017 and now all my `.js` files with jsx syntax in them are giving me errors.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix that and why VS Code understands the syntax while VS 2017 doesn't?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/javascript-in-vs-2017#JSX